# Execute script function using JPA

Tags: jpa, hsqldb

I am using a database that runs in memory (HSQL) for unit test. But in my real database I have some functions defined that I might need in my database in memory for testing.

Is there a way of creating functions SQL in my database with Java code?

Comment: I don't think this is a great idea, for testing I'd recommend **mocking** the database. There is even framework that makes this extremely easy to set up: [mockito](http://mockito.org/)

Comment: @Oceans, thanks for your answer i will try it. But i have to insist in my question if there exists some way of doing that because for my tests i use HSQL and in my app i use PostgreSQL. I also have things configurated in that way. So i wanna test my question.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can always execute any SQL with `EntityManager.createNativeQuery`:

```
EntityManager em = ...
em.createNativeQuery("CREATE FUNCTION ...").executeUpdate();
```

You can call that during the startup of your application.

*Remark:* In Hibernate you need to escape any `:` with `\` because it tries to replace parameters in the SQL.